# How do I not auto-select auto-suggestions in the address bar of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I like to see auto suggestions when I'm typing in the address bar, but I hate it when chrome auto-selects one of those as I'm typing.  For example, let's say I search for

```
vanilla ice cream with sprinkles[Enter]
```

(where I hit the Enter key at the end there).  Then, a minute later, I just want to search for

```
vanilla ice cream[Enter]
```

because I just remembered I hate sprinkles.  Chrome auto suggests my previous search, which includes `with sprinkles`, and when I hit Enter, it just goes to that search.  But I didn't want the sprinkles!

[I'm using the current version of chrome on the current version of OS X.]

Can I disable that "feature" without disabling the suggestions themselves?

Comment: The chromium devs do not want to change this behavior.

Comment: This question is totally a duplicate of that other one.  It's nice to know [I'm not alone](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/0DR-pLIVI5g) in hating the aggressive replacement of what I've typed.